# ASP.NET MVC 4 application can't run on .NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-3.5, .net-4.5

We have 1 prod and 1 dev server, both running .NET 3.5. I'm trying to build an ASP.NET MVC 4 application, but it requires at least .NET 4.0.

I can't just buy another IIS server and we can't upgrade our existing ones because there are other much larger applications that run on .NET 3.5.

What are my options?

Comment: Why can't you install .NET 4.0 on your server?

Comment: You can install .net 4 and .net 3.5 side by side.

Comment: Oh ok -- I was unaware this was possible. Thanks very much!

Comment: Steve, one caveat about different versions of .NET running side by side on your servers... you will need to have different Application Pools for each of the different framework versions. In other words, if you need to run your 3.5 apps IN 3.5 mode, you need to have  separate 3.5 and 4.0 pools.

Comment: Thanks da7rutrak, I'll try to remember that when we set it up.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot upgrade to .NET framework 4.0 then and are tied to .NET framework 3.5 then you will have to downgrade your application to MVC 2.0. Which ought not to be difficult UNLESS your using LOTS of NEW features which are only in MVC 4.0 and not in MVC 2.0 Also having said that, you may even be able to create workarounds to some of them if not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can run Asp.Net 2.0 and Asp.Net 4.0 side by side. Find more information here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a99txfy5(v=vs.100).aspx